# Must we use the Thevenin to simplify the circuit first before we calculate the stability factor of this circuit?

Tags: amplifier, bjt

There is a voltage divider bias schematic:

[image]

Lots of books will use the Thevenin (\$R_{th}=R_{B1}||R_{B2}\$) to simplify the circuit and calculate the stability factor, just like in this [video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6wvwspLkkc) and the stability fsctor is \$S=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta (R_E)}{R_{th}+R_E}}\$

I calculated the stability factor  without using Thevenin, but the result wrong, so I wonder if we must use the Thevenin to simplify the circuit first before we calculate the stability factor of this circuit.  If yes,why? If no, where am I wrong in my calculation?

Here is my calculation:

\$V_{CC}=i_c R_C+V_{CE}+i_E R_E+(i_B+i_{B2})R_{B1}+i_{B2}R_{B2}+V_{BE}\$

and \$i_E=i_c+i_B\$ so

\$V_{CC}=i_c R_C+V_{CE}+(i_c+i_B) R_E+(i_B+i_{B2})R_{B1}+i_{B2}R_{B2}+V_{BE}\$ then

\$i_B=\frac{V_{CC}-(i_c (R_C+R_E))-V_{CE}-i_{B2}R_{B1}-i_{B2}R_{B2}-V_{BE}}{R_{B1}+R_E}\$

And as we know,the definition of stability factor is \$S=\frac{\partial i_c}{\partial i_{co}}\$, \$i_{co}\$ is the reverse saturation current

and  \$i_c=\beta i_B+(1+\beta )i_{co}\$, now we can get

\$i_c=\beta \frac{V_{CC}-(i_c (R_C+R_E))-V_{CE}-i_{B2}R_{B1}-i_{B2}R_{B2}-V_{BE}}{R_{B1}+R_E}+(1+\beta )i_{co}\$

Now

\$\frac{\partial i_c}{\partial i_c}=1=\beta \frac{- (R_C+R_E)}{R_{B1}+R_E}+(1+\beta )\frac{1}{S}\$ so the stability factor \$S=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta (R_C+R_E)}{R_{B1}+R_E}}\$.

Now I have a different stability factor.  Where did I wrong when I calculated the stability factor without simplifying the circuit first?

Comment: @user287001 why should we modify Ic=(1+\beta )Ico+(\beta)Ib to  Ic=Ico+(\beta)Ib?

Comment: Just saw that your presentation is used in many places. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: The first equation in your calculation should be: \$V_{CC}=i_c R_C+V_{CE}+i_E R_E\$. I haven't checked any further. The currents should be upper case if they are DC biasing; lower case is normally used for signals.

Comment: I agree with @chu - it's wrong to sling in the base currents.

Comment: @Chu why isn't\$V_{CC}=i_c R_C+V_{CE}+i_E R_E+(i_B+i_{B2})R_{B1}+i_{B2}R_{B2}+V_{BE}\$??it seems that we just ignore the base current

Comment: There are several ways of going on a journey from the ground rail (0 V) to the top rail \$(V_{CC})\$: (i) up through the source, \$V_{CC}\$; (ii) up through \$i_ER_E\$, then up through \$V_{CE}\$, then up through \$i_C R_C\$. (iii) up through \$i_{B2}R_{B2}\$ then up through \$(i_B+i_{B2})R_{B1}\$; (iv) up through \$i_ER_E\$, then up through \$V_{BE}\$, then up through \$(i_B+i_{B2})R_{B1}\$. All of these journeys take you up by \$V_{CC}\$.

Comment: ... there's another journey that goes via \$i_{B2}R_{B2}\$, then \$V_{CB}\$, then \$i_CR_C\$.

Comment: ... and yet another, via \$i_ER_E\$, then \$V_{BE}\$, then \$V_{CB}\$, then \$i_CR_C\$.